# Hacer que una Imagen "huya" de otra

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css

Debo decir primero que todo, que soy un *newbie*, estoy reciclándome en temas de programación. Aun siendo programador hacía más de 6 años que no tocaba nada. Así que os imploro paciencia.

Estoy practicando cosas con `JavaScript`, resulta que quiero hacer que una imagen se mueva con las teclas de las flechas y al "encontrarse" con otra imagen, esta ultima huya.

El código de mover la primera imagen con las flechas ya funciona, lo que no me funciona es el "cuando se encuentren, que la otra cambie de posición".

```js
function leftArrowPressed () {
  var element = document.getElementById("pimientos");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

function rightArrowPressed () {
  var element = document.getElementById("pimientos");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
}

function upArrowPressed () {
  var element = document.getElementById("pimientos");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
}

function downArrowPressed () {
  var element = document.getElementById("pimientos");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
}

function moveSelection (evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 38:
      upArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 40:
      downArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
};

function docReady () {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection, quemepilla);
}

function quemepilla (evt) {
  var elementPimi = document.getElementById("pimientos");
  var elementPC = document.getElementById("pc");

  if (elementPC.style.top || elementPC.style.left === elementPimi.style.top || elementPimi.style.left) {
    elementPC.style.top = parseInt(elementPC.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
    elementPC.style.top = parseInt(elementPC.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
    elementPC.style.left = parseInt(elementPC.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
    elementPC.style.left = parseInt(elementPC.style.left) - 5 + 'px';

  }

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docReady);
```

```html
<img src="carapimi.png" alt="" id="pimientos" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="45" width="45">
<img src="pc.svg" alt="" id="pc" style="position:absolute;left:100px; top:100px;" height="45" width="45">
```

Comment: Si he entendido bien, lo que pretendes es por ejemplo mover la imagen de los pimientos cerca de la imagen pc y que la imagen pc huya... ¿pero cómo quieres que huya? Desaparecer, moverse al top, etc. Da algún detalle más porfi

Comment: Quiero que la imagen PC se mueva de manera que pimientos no llegue NUNCA a tocarla.

Pero quiero que PC se mueva justo cuando pimiento esté a punto de llegar a PC. No se si me explico XD

Comment: Josep, ¿solucionaste tu problema? Por favor tómate un minuto para marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes corregir la llamada a `quemepilla` (?) porque nunca se hace. El tercer parámetro sirve para indicar indicar si dicho handler debe *capturar* el evento ni bien este es disparado (*capture*) o si debe de ejecutarse al final (*bubble*).

> Los handlers añadidos mediante `addEventListener` **son ejecutados en el orden en el que se añaden a un determinado evento**. De esta manera, si pasas `true` como tercer parámetro, estás diciendo que cuando se dispare un evento dicho handler *capturará* el mismo para proceder con su ejecución, teniendo así prioridad sobre el resto de handlers.

La llamada a `quemepilla`, entonces, debes hacerla, luego del switch para evaluar si existe colisión.

---

Lo primero que hay que hacer es obtener en cada pintado las coordenadas (top, right, bottom y left) de las imágenes. Luego, mediante comparaciones de ellas, **conocer en qué lado se produce la colisión** para moverse en dirección contraria.

**Ejemplo (ver en pantalla completa)**

```js
let $cheese;
let $mouse;
let $debug;

//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $cheese = document.getElementById('cheese');
  $mouse = document.getElementById('mouse');
  $debug = document.getElementById('debug');
  const $board = document.getElementById('board');

  const width = $cheese.offsetWidth;
  const height = $cheese.offsetHeight;
  const boardWidth = board.offsetWidth;
  const boardHeight = board.offsetHeight;
  const axisX = (boardWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
  const axisY = (boardHeight / 2) - (height / 2);
  $cheese.style.left = axisX + 'px';
  $cheese.style.top = axisY + 'px';

  document.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
//});

function leftArrowPressed() {
  const left = parseInt($mouse.style.left);
  $mouse.style.left = left - 5 + 'px';
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  const left = parseInt($mouse.style.left);
  $mouse.style.left = left + 5 + 'px';
}

function upArrowPressed() {
  const top = parseInt($mouse.style.top);
  $mouse.style.top = top - 5 + 'px';
}

function downArrowPressed() {
  const top = parseInt($mouse.style.top);
  $mouse.style.top = top + 5 + 'px';
}

function moveSelection(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 38:
      upArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 40:
      downArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
  draw();
}

function debug({
  mouse,
  cheese
}) {
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  const mouseSpan = document.createElement('span');
  const cheeseSpan = document.createElement('span');
  paragraph.appendChild(mouseSpan);
  paragraph.appendChild(cheeseSpan);
  mouseSpan.textContent = `
      Mouse: Top: ${mouse.top}, Right: ${mouse.right},
      Bottom: ${mouse.bottom}, Left: ${mouse.left}
    `.replace(/\n/g, '');
  cheeseSpan.textContent = `
      Cheese: Top: ${cheese.top}, Right: ${cheese.right},
      Bottom: ${cheese.bottom}, Left: ${cheese.left}`;
  // add paragraph to debug
  $debug
    .querySelector('article')
    .appendChild(paragraph);
  // set a fixed width to draw correctly the bottom border
  paragraph.style.width = `${paragraph.scrollWidth}px`;
}

function draw(evt) {
  const {
    top: mouseTop,
    right: mouseRight,
    bottom: mouseBottom,
    left: mouseLeft
  } = $mouse.getBoundingClientRect();
  const {
    top: cheeseTop,
    right: cheeseRight,
    bottom: cheeseBottom,
    left: cheeseLeft
  } = $cheese.getBoundingClientRect();
  debug({
    mouse: {
      top: mouseTop,
      right: mouseRight,
      bottom: mouseBottom,
      left: mouseLeft
    },
    cheese: {
      top: cheeseTop,
      right: cheeseRight,
      bottom: cheeseBottom,
      left: cheeseLeft
    }
  });
  // El queso se mueve hacia la derecha
  if (
    (cheeseLeft - mouseRight <= 5 && cheeseLeft - mouseRight > 0) &&
    (mouseBottom >= cheeseTop && mouseBottom <= cheeseBottom)
  ) {
    $cheese.style.left = `${cheeseLeft + 5}px`;
  }

  // El queso se mueve hacia la izquierda
  else if (
    (mouseLeft - cheeseRight <= 5 && mouseLeft - cheeseRight > 0) &&
    (mouseBottom >= cheeseTop && mouseBottom <= cheeseBottom)
  ) {
    $cheese.style.left = `${cheeseLeft - 5}px`;
  }

  // El queso se mueve hacia abajo
  else if (
    (cheeseTop - mouseBottom <= 5 && cheeseTop - mouseBottom > 0) &&
    (mouseLeft >= cheeseLeft && mouseRight <= cheeseRight + 5)
  ) {
    $cheese.style.top = `${cheeseTop + 5}px`;
  }

  // El queso se mueve hacia arriba
  else if (
    (mouseTop - cheeseBottom <= 5 && mouseTop - cheeseBottom > 0) &&
    (mouseLeft >= cheeseLeft && mouseRight <= cheeseRight + 5)
  ) {
    $cheese.style.top = `${cheeseTop - 5}px`;
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  paddign: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#board {
  flex: 1;
}

#debug {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  max-width: 280px;
}

#debug h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #555;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#debug article {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#debug article p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

#debug article p span {
  color: #1976D2;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>DOM collision</title>
</head>

<body>
  <article id="board">
    <img src="http://www.clipartlord.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/mouse-face.png" alt="mouse" id="mouse" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="45" width="45" />
    <img src="http://images.wikia.com/clubpenguin/images/e/e0/Cheese_Emote.png" alt="cheese" id="cheese" style="position:absolute" height="45" width="45" />
  </article>
  <section id="debug">
    <h3>Debug</h3>
    <article>

    </article>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Es un prototipo bastante sencillo, por cuestiones de tiempo no puedo ponerte algo más complejo, pero te servirá para que partas desde allí. Para que se produzca correctamente el desplazamiento, cerciórate *que el ratón esté entre las dimensiones (medio) del queso*.

Answer (score 2):

Pues básicamente debes hacer dos cosas:

1. Detectar si las dos imágenes se solapan (veo que has realizado un intento en tu código)
2. Si las imágenes se solapan, mover la imagen a una nueva posición.

Un problema que tienes en tu código es que estás intentando llamar a dos funciones desde un único [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), el tercer parámetro de un `addEventListener` es `useCapture` y es un `boleano`.

Otro problema es la manera en que intentas hacer las condiciones, en la siguiente condición:

```
elementPC.style.top || elementPC.style.left === elementPimi.style.top || elementPimi.style.left
```

Lo que estás diciendo es, si `elementPC.style.top` es `true` o `elementPC.style.left` es igual a `elementPimi.style.top` o `elementPimi.style.left` es `true` (Esas variable se tomarán como `true` si su valor es diferente de `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` o `0`). La anterior condición no chequeará si las imágenes se solapan porque no hace los chequeos necesarios.

Otra cosa que no funcionaría bien en tu código es la nueva posición que le asignas a la imagen:

```
elementPC.style.top = parseInt(elementPC.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
elementPC.style.top = parseInt(elementPC.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
elementPC.style.left = parseInt(elementPC.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
elementPC.style.left = parseInt(elementPC.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
```

Básicamente mueves la imagen cinco pixeles positivos y después cinco pixeles negativos, por lo que el resultado será que la imagen se queda en el mismo sitio.

Analiza el algoritmo que te propongo para saber si las dos imágenes se intersectan en alguna zona, básicamente es comprobar si las imágenes **no** se solapan y aplicarle a este chequeo un [LOGICAL NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos):

```
if (!(left1 + width1 < left2 || left2 + width2 < left1 || top1 + height1 < top2 || top2 + height2 < top1)) {
    ...
}
```

Después de comprobar que las imágenes se intersectan debes mover la imagen 2 a una nueva posición, ya esto depende de lo que desees hacer y no lo dejas claro en tu pregunta, pero una solución sería mover la imagen con un valor que sea el doble de sus dimensiones, y como las dos imágenes tienen las mismas dimensiones, nos aseguramos que la nueva posición no coincidirá con la posición de la primera imagen.

> Para lograr detectar las coordenadas de los elementos un método muy útil es [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Si necesitas soportar a navegadores menores que IE9 este método no te serviría y creo que sería más útil usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) o similar.
>
> Un nuevo reto que tendrás será lograr que las imágenes al moverse no se salgan de los límites del *viewport*. Creo que tomando como base el siguiente código te será más fácil lograrlo.

```js
var pimientos = document.getElementById("pimientos");
var elementPC = document.getElementById("pc");

function moveElement (element, prop, value) {

  var offset = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  element.style[prop] = (offset[prop] + value) + "px";
  
  checkCollision();
  
}

function moveSelection (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      moveElement(pimientos, "left", -5);
      break;
    case 39:
      moveElement(pimientos, "left", 5);
      break;
    case 38:
      moveElement(pimientos, "top", -5);
      break;
    case 40:
      moveElement(pimientos, "top", 5);
      break;
  }
};

function runAway () {

  var offset = elementPC.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  var rX = Math.round(1 - Math.random() * 2);
  var rY = Math.round(1 - Math.random() * 2);
  var posX = offset.left + offset.width * 2 * rX;
  var posY = offset.top + offset.height * 2 * rY;
  
  elementPC.style.left = posX + "px";
  elementPC.style.top = posY + "px";

}

function checkCollision () {

  var offset1 = pimientos.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offset2 = elementPC.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if (
    !(offset1.left + offset1.width < offset2.left ||
      offset2.left + offset2.width < offset1.left ||
      offset1.top + offset1.height < offset2.top ||
      offset2.top + offset2.height < offset1.top)
  ) {
  
    runAway();
  
  }

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSelection);

});
```

```css
#pimientos,
#pc {
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
}

#pimientos {
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#pc {
  background: blue;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pimientos"></div>
<div id="pc"></div>
```

Aquí te dejo [un jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/vf57mgpe/) con el mismo código situado más arriba. No sé por qué funciona mejor ahí que en el *snippet* de `SO`.